# How to get the remaining time out of setInterval() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```js
function startTimer(time) {
  var countDown = 0;
  var time1 = time * 60;
  x = setInterval(function() {
    time2 = time1--;
    if (time2 > 0) {
      document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = time2;
    } else if (time2 == 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
startTimer(30)
```

```html
<span id=displayTime></span>
```

how could I get the remaining time out of this code and use them for pause/resume purpose. (I am planning to apply that value in to the function).

I tried creating 2 buttons for pause and resume but not working.

```
 $("#start").on("click",function(){
   if (time2 < setTime){
     startTimer(time2);
   }
   else{
     startTimer(setTime);
   }

   });
   $("#stop").on("click",function(){
     clearInterval(x);
    })
    });
```

Comment: what problem do you encounter?

Comment: I want to get the remaining time out of that function.

Comment: for me it works like expected if you remove `time1 = time * 60` and do `time1 = time`

Comment: there is no timeout here you have a setInterval which will keep executing the function every 1000 ms as you have.. and inside that you have a logic which terminate it when time2 variable is 0... so if you need when clearInternal will be called just access the variable time2 that should have the value

Answer (score 1):

I took time2 out of the function and also made x available outside the function. This we can use to start/ resume the timer.

```js
var time2;
var timer;
function startTimer(time) {
  var countDown = 0;
  var time1 = time * 60;
  x = setInterval(function() {
    time2 = time1--;
    if (time2 > 0) {
      document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = time2;
    } else if (time2 == 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
  }, 1000);
  return x;
}

function pauseTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
function resumeTimer() {
  time = time2/60 || 30;
  timer = startTimer(time);
}
```

```html
<span id=displayTime></span>
<button onclick="pauseTimer()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="resumeTimer()">Start/Resume</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses an input box to set the start time, setting the input to `readonly` might be desired if you don't want the user to change the value.

```js
var timerInterval = null;

function startTimer(time) {
  // Update input every second
  return setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("displayTime").value = --time;
    if (time < 1) {
      pause();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function start() {
  // Get the current time to begin from
  var timeToStartFrom = document.getElementById("displayTime").value;
  timerInterval = startTimer(timeToStartFrom);
}

function pause() {
  // Clear the interval to stop the timer
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
```

```html
<input id=displayTime value=30 />
<button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Lastly, keep in mind this is not an accurate timer. If a user hits `Pause` the timer will increase by the difference between the last whole second and the passed time in that second. (ex: Pause at 28.1 seconds remaining, the input will still show 29 seconds, restarting will begin at 29 seconds. This effectively added 0.9 seconds to the timer.)

There are many libraries based on accurate time keeping, I would suggest looking for those for anything more than a basic example.